# Access GUI elements before it is created?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In Activity lifecycle the onActivityResult method is called before the onCreate methode, where all my buttons etc. are initialized.
How is it possible to access them though? Thx for some background knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to an onActivityResult event should happen is if you used startActivityForResult to create the new activity that generates that event.

Which means your calling activity should be in the stack and already created but just paused so your onCreate was already called.

Unless there is an orientation change in between which I have never tried and poses an interesting question.

Are you having an issue or just trying to understand the mechanism?  If you are having and issue post some code.

Comment: mh I think I made a mistake and got confused about the order of callbacks when restoring my actvitiy.. Thought it was onActivityResult before onCreate, but actually it is reverse.